# Use of numChildren and getChildAt in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

What are the main uses of `numChildren` and `getChildAt` in AS3.

Kindly help me with a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a movieclip '**mcA'**
mcA contains another 3 movieclips **'mcB'**, **'mcC'**, **'mcD'.**
Now, we can say thet **mcB**, **mcC** and **mcD** are childs of **mcA**
so if we want to know how much childs an MovieClip have, we can use **movieclip.numChildren**.
In our case we have:

```
mcA.numChildren  -> this is equals to 3
trace(mcA.numChildren); //output 3
trace(mcB.numChildren); //output 0
```

**getChildAt** is a metod/function with one parameter that indicates the index/layer of children.
this method will return the children at that index, if layer exists.

for example:

```
   mcA :
        index0- mcC
        index1 - mcD
        index2 - mcB
```

if this is the structure of **mcA** then:

```
mcA.getChildAt(0); //this will return mcC
mcA.getChildAt(1); //this will return mcD
mcA.getChildAt(2); //this will return mcB
mcA.getChildAt(3); //this is error 'The supplied index is out of bounds ...'
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildAt();